# Importance of $q$-analog

Tags: combinatorics, q-analogs

I am currently studying q-analog, but I was actually confused on what its actual purpose is. Like I see all these manipulations using $q$, but I have little idea on what they represent. Sure the series and manipulations they look nice, and work out nicely, but again quite lost on what its actual purpose is.

I would appreciate some little background information and the actual use and intuitive interpretation of what they represent in mathematics.

Comment: Perhaps, instead of counting all elements in a set, you would like to find the distribution of some combinatorial statistic on that set. Use that statistic as the exponent of $q$, then. For example, the $q$-binomial coefficient gives the distribution of the inversion statistic on binary strings with a given number of $0$'s and $1$'s.

Comment: I am sorry, but maybe are there some sources where it explains these things in more detail. Im never satisfied with what they still mean.

Comment: Try [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) or [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-BinomialCoefficient.html) pages on $q$-binomials, for example. Here is [another source](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~pjc/Teaching/MT5821/1/l6.pdf), but there are plenty more, just google some key words.

Comment: It is just that all these sources seem to be alittle more technical but ok.

Comment: “It’s not a bug, it’s a feature.”

Answer (score 2):

> The nice and gentle surveys
>
> - *[The q-binomial Theorem](https://www.aucklandmaths.org.nz/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/The-q-binomial-theorem.pdf)* by Shaun Cooper
> - *[On the q-binomial coefficients and binomial congruences](http://arminstraub.com/downloads/slides/2012qbinomials-illinois.pdf)* by Armin Straub
>
>   might be helpful. The first presents a connection with enumeration of lattice paths.
>
> The classic
>
> - *[Integer Partitions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521600901)* by George E. Andrews and Kimmo Eriksson is *the*  introductory text to integer partitions for beginners. $q$-related material starts with Chapter 7 *Gaussian polynomials*.
>
> A book about the  development of $q$-calculus from a historical perspective and providing many examples of applications is
>
> - *[The History of q-Calculus and a new method](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.63.274&rep=rep1&type=pdf)* by Thomas Ernst

Answer (score 2):

Recently, some researchers are considering to apply $q$-analogs to numerical methods. For example, there is a $q$-Newton method (with local convergence):

[Rajkovic, P. M., Stankovic, M. S., & Marinkovic, S. D. (2003). On $q$-iterative methods for solving equations and systems. Novi Sad J. Math, 33(2), 127-137.](http://emis.ams.org/journals/NSJOM/Papers/33_2/nsjom_33_2_127_137.pdf)

A $q$-epsilon algorithm is also developed:

He, Y., Hu, X. B., & Tam, H. W. (2009). A $q$-difference version of the ϵ-algorithm. Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical, 42(9), 095202.

$q$-analogs of numerical methods use $q$-derivative instead of the ordinary derivative. In other words, it provides derivative-free algorithms. This is the importance of $q$-analogs in numerical analysis.